# Compare between parameter and add exception SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have two parameters which specify start time and end time. I would like to prompt the error( error message) when user select end time is smaller than start time. Any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by cascading parameters:

1. Create the dataset for the **@start_time** parameter (ex. Dataset_starttime)
2. Set available values for **@start_time** parameter to Dataset_starttime
3. Create the dataset for **@end_time**  parameter (ex.Dataset_endtime) using a statement similar to:

> SELECT time_column
>   FROM time_table
>   WHERE time_column >  @start_time

4. Set available values for **@end_time** parameter to Dataset_endtime

Now your end_time parameter values that users can select will always be later than the start time.

For more info on cascading parameters: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337169.aspx